# Tokenization is skipped for long lines for performance reasons. The length of a long line can be configured via `editor.maxTokenizationLineLength`

Tags: node.js, express, visual-studio-code

I'm at a loss here. I have a Node.js server built for my project and out of nowhere, I started getting this error when I try to run the server in VSCode:

Tokenization is skipped for long lines for performance reasons. The length of a long line can be configured via `editor.maxTokenizationLineLength`.

I had edited some of my functions in my controller before this started. I discarded all changes but the error still persists. I don't understand what has changed for this to happen. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

My code is here if you want to take a look
https://github.com/Kevinclane/timeclock

Comment: for which file do you get this message

Comment: it pulls up the esm.js during the debugger process

Comment: https://youtu.be/dau3-YbPS0w

I made a short video showing it happen. The error window didn't show up this time because it had already come up last time I tried to run it.

Comment: that file is all on one line. You must have made a programming error that causes `esm.js` to crash or throw an exception. Use git to find the commit that first failed and see what you have changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Apparently, just toggling the options for breakpoints on caught and uncaught exceptions causes it to fail... Doesn't make sense, but it works now.

Answer (score 22):

I fixed this problem by increasing `Max Tokenization Length` in VSCode :

1. Go to `File--> Preferences--> Setting`
2. Search for `Max Tokenization Length`
   [image]
3. Change the default value to 2000000

**I hope this will help**

Comment: I tried to edit this as well and set it to a ridiculously large number and it was still failing. It turns it was just because I had selected for all breakpoints to be hit for caught and uncaught exceptions. I wasn't sure what it did and I selected it, then forgot all about it and couldn't figure out what was going on. Worked fine after I turned them off. Still seems strange that it would fail on that just by seeing the breakpoint though.

Thank you for taking time to try to address this issue though! It is appreciated.

Comment: Obs worth mentioning: I was having issues with the entire editor crashing when opening a specific file with a really long line and I found (with `code --verbose`) that this change was causing it. I made this setting 200 thousand instead to compromise. Not sure why they didn't make tokenization work in a separate thread or process, it just seems like a bad design choice from a user's perspective.

Comment: Edit: there's a setting to change this, I'll post it as an answer for higher visibility.

Answer (score 2):

I found the hard way that besides increasing the Max Tokenization Length as suggested by @Ousama, in order to avoid VS Code from crashing or becoming entirely unresponsive you might also want to enable the Async Tokenization option in the settings. Otherwise files with really long lines will make VS Code unresponsive. I'm not sure why this was not made default.

[image: "Async Tokenization" option in the settings checked]

- [GitHub issue introducing Async Tokenization](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/147066).

Answer (score 0):

This is not actually an error as such. If you assign really long length string to a variable, you might see this:

[image]

However, you will be still able to use that variable.

Answer (score 0):

VScode has for some languages an extra maxTokenizationLineLength.

Comment: Hi, there is another answer with this content. Be sure to read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).Thank you